# Behavior of electrons (magical?)

Tags: electrons, atoms

so as I was reading in a book some thing caught my eye and I was like well if I'm confused better go to physics stack exchange here is what it said "scientists proved that sub-atomic particles like electrons could be at two places at once" is this true or did the book just make it up?

Comment: I changed your title because I think this is what is gathering the - votes for you. magic is not popular in physics sites :)

Answer (score 1):

> "scientists proved that sub-atomic particles like electrons could be at two places at once" is this true or did the book just make it up?

This is a misstatement of what the quantum mechanical nature of small dimensions is. In atomic dimensions quantum mechanics rules and , in contrast to mechanics, it does not predict trajectories like the orbits of planets, but probability loci, called [orbitals.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbital). To predict where an electron is one can give only a probability of finding it at (x,y,z,t). So the statement is a misunderstanding of what a probability space distribution means. It does not mean "the electron is all over the place" but "the electron **may** be found all over the space defined by the orbital when measured"